# How to use class in Python for write a library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a library in Python that I'll use for a project. Unfortunately I'm not confident with Python. This is a simple case to explain my problem. The error is: No value for argument 'int' in unbound method callpylint(no-value-for-parameter), but I don't know what it means. If my aim is not clear, I want a class (Library in this case) in which there are some functions that I need when I'm working in the other class (DoStuff in this case).

```
class Library:
   def someFunction(self, int):
      return (int + int)


class DoStuff:
   def __init__(self, something):
      self.something = something

   def run(self):
      print(Library.someFunction(2))
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `someFunction` needs instance - ie. `a = Library()` `a.someFunction(2)` or shorter `Library().someFunction(2)` - in both situations you need `()` after `Library` to create instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. This code doesn't produce an error by itself. It looks like the error is coming from a linter? You need to make a [mre]. That said, @furas is right, you're calling `Library.someFunction` like it's a class method, but it's an instance method.

Comment: how do you use this class ? When do you get this error ? Show full error message, not only last line. I see word `lint` in message so maybe it is not error but warning created by tool `lint` in some `IDE`. Message shows error in `callpylin()` but I don't see it in your code.

Comment: There's no apparent need for a class here. `someFunction` can simply be a module-level function.

Comment: I feel like the user posted enough information to be able to reproduce the error. By just making a 'DoStuff' object and calling run on it, I got the exact error that OP provided. This question is pretty good for a first attempt. Could be better, but there is enough information to answer it.

Comment: Thank you, it was so simple using `Library().someFunction(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are seeing an error is that you are calling 'some function' directly on the class, and not on an object of the class.

So the way classes work is that they define a 'blueprint' for objects. But you have to then still create the object. In the code below I show how you can modify your code so that you create a library, and then call the method on that object.

The reason that the error message says that 'int' has no value is because the number (2) which you gave it got sent to the 'self' argument. If you call a method on an object, that object automatically becomes the 'self' argument value. But if you call it directly, then your number will go to 'self', and there will be no value for the 'int' argument.

Side note, don't call your arguments 'int'. Call them 'integer' or '_int'. 'int' is a reserved word.

If you don't want to make an object before calling a method, then there are ways to do this. But in those cases, the method should usually just be a flat function. There is little reason to put a function in a class if you aren't going to be making objects.

```
class Library:
   def someFunction(self, int):
      return (int + int)


class DoStuff:
   def __init__(self, something):
      self.something = something

   def run(self):
      library = Library()
      print(library.someFunction(2))


def main():
    do_stuff = DoStuff('hello')

    do_stuff.run()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```